# Storing data in Spring state machine?

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I am making mulitplayer quiz like game. I have chosen to use spring state machines to model each individual instance of the game on the server using `@EnableStateMachineFactory`. But, I need every instance of the state machine to have additional game data/state info, and to init that data on the state machine startup with some custom startup data (like player usernames for example). Is `ExtendedState` intended for such stuff and if it is how to send custom initial extended state data when creating the state machine with factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `ExtendedState` is only way to store data within a machine itself. I've used it like that so it's ok.

Order to initialize `ExtendedState` I'd use machine's initial action which is executed when initial state entry logic happens. In UML machine model it's purpose by definition is to init machine.

[Initial State](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#initial-state)

Comment: Thanks. I have already implemented my machine like this with the initialisation on the first event, but thanks for the confirmation anyway.